# Breakpoint on any string assignment if string contains a certain substring

Tags: javascript, debugging, breakpoints

Can I put a data breakpoint which triggers if any variable is assigned to a string containing a certain substring?

For example, I want to reverse-engineer how a URL containing `&ctoken=` is constructed. It's done with complicated JavaScript where the goal is to obfuscate it.

If I could tell the JS VM to monitor all string variables and break when a certain substring appears on **any** variable, this would help me a lot.

Is this possible?

Comment: I understand the technical requirement. Can you also write the business requirement.

Comment: Depending on your IDE you can put conditional breakpoints which only cause the code to stop executing if a certain condition is met. In your case you could do something along the lines of:

`myString.search("&ctoken=") !== -1`

Comment: As I understand, you want to create `global conditional breakpoint`, but  unfortunately it's unpossible. [Description of possible types of breakpoints (Chrome)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints)

Comment: @ThomasCook Yes, only with the caveat that it should work for any string variable, not just for a particular variable with a particular name. That is, the condition is "if at any point of execution, any variable at all holds a string that contains a certain substring, then break execution".

Comment: A partial solution can be override che String constructor method and set breakpoint on it. This cannot work for assignment `var str = "Hello"` but works with `var str = new String("Hello");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before I start - as of my knowledge this is not possible.

What you'd need (even before creating the debugging feature) is the raw string types already boxed to `String` the native built-in object and `String` then already proxied.

Some more explanation:

only having

```
const s = "hi"
```

is not yet an instance of `String` - the built-in native object, which is supplied by the ECMAScript implementation to your scope - but a raw type. 
Such raw types are nothing more than pointers to a raw data memory reference. I even assume there are built in pools like in Java to optimize cases like

```
const s = "hi"
const x = new String("hi")
```

to be the same memory reference of the data object. but the later of course would be boxed by `String`.
http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1String.html

On raw types we couldn't - even if we wanted to - add a subscriber.

for example then:

```
s.charAt(i)
```

will autobox `s` to its wrapper `String`.

to observe every raw type would mean that we'd have to box all raw strings to `String` which wouldn't be a good thing for performance at all.

not only that but also the implementation of `String` itself would have to allow us to add a subscriber and therefore be proxied already.

in JS such proxy would look like this (to make it more understandable what I mean by proxied):

```
var proxiedString = new Proxy(String, {
  defineProperty(target, propKey, propDesc) {
    console.log('defined a new string')
  },
  set(obj, prop, value) {
    console.log('set a new value to a string')
  }
});

proxiedString.x = 'newPropValue'
```

and that again I guess - wouldn't be good for performance.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use condition breakpoints at browser devTools, by right
   click with a menu.
2. If you can write a js somewhere in a page, you
   can do this:

.

```
    if(window.location.pathname.indexOf("&ctoken=") > -1){ 
       debugger;// browser will put breakpoint automaticaly here, if condition  is trully.
       console.dir(window.location);
    }
```